# AngularJS ng-click not firing controller method

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm sure everyone has seen questions of a similar ilk, and trust me when I say I have read all of them in trying to find an answer. But alas without success. So here goes.

With the below code, why can I not get an alert?

I have an ASP.Net MVC4 Web API application with AngularJS thrown in. I have pared down the code as much as I can.

I know that my AngularJS setup is working correctly because on loading my view it correctly gets (via a Web API call) and displays data from the database into a table (the GetAllRisks function). Given that the Edit button is within the controller, I shouldn't have any scope issues.

NB: the dir-paginate directive and controls are taken from Michael Bromley's excellent post [here](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/108/paginate-almost-anything-in-angularjs).

I would appreciate any thoughts as my day has degenerated into banging my head against my desk.

Thanks,

Ash

**module.js**

```
var app = angular.module("OpenBoxExtraModule", ["angularUtils.directives.dirPagination"]);
```

**service.js**

```
app.service('OpenBoxExtraService', function ($http) {
//Get All Risks
this.getAllRisks = function () {
    return $http.get("/api/RiskApi");
}});
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller("RiskController", function ($scope, OpenBoxExtraService) {

//On load
GetAllRisks();

function GetAllRisks() {
    var promiseGet = OpenBoxExtraService.getAllRisks();
    promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.Risks = pl.data },
        function (errorPl) {
            $log.error("Some error in getting risks.", errorPl);
        });
    }

$scope.ash = function () {
    alert("Bananarama!");}

});
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="OpenBoxExtraModule">
<head>
    <title>Risks</title>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/AngularJS/Pagination/dirPagination.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/AngularJS/module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/AngularJS/service.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/AngularJS/controller.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<div ng-controller="RiskController">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Risk ID</th>
            <th>i3_n_omr</th>
            <th>i3_n_2_uwdata_key</th>
            <th>Risk Reference</th>
            <th>Pure Facultative</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr dir-paginate="risk in Risks | itemsPerPage: 15">
            <td><span>{{risk.RiskID}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{risk.i3_n_omr}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{risk.i3_n_2_uwdata_key}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{risk.RiskReference}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{risk.PureFacultative}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{risk.TimestampColumn}}</span></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="Edit" value="Edit" ng-click="ash()"/></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <div>
            <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" template-url="~/Scripts/AngularJS/Pagination/dirPagination.tpl.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how about changing input type to button and then fire ng-click??

Comment: I couldn't find a solution to your problem, here's my basic try - http://plnkr.co/edit/OhV44v1bdEibVfJKo4A2.  Have you tried using 'angular.bootstrap' like in this article - https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data#automatically-bootstrapping-an-angularjs-application instead of using ng-app.  You could see whether the function actually made it to the controller's scope by using the Angular chrome dev tools extension? All the best! :)

Comment: Thanks @FrailWords. I will look into the bootstrap. I am stuck with IE so can't use the Chrome tools. But why wouldn't the function make it to the controller's scope?

Comment: @TheDumbRadish, I don't know the reason but thats the only possibility in terms of what you are seeing i.e. the scope function not getting called.  But you do see the API call getting through, so maybe its going through with the HTTP promise partl but failing on the 'digest' part? Just a hunch.

Comment: For IE debugging, you could use the console statement like - angular.element(document.getElementById("Edit")).scope()  to get the scope for the button and see if the function is there and maybe fire it from the console.

Comment: Again, thanks @FrailWords

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use ng-click attribute on input with angularjs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input.

use onFocus javascript event

```
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()">
```

or try to surround your input with div or span and add ng-click on it.

Comment: I can't use ng-click on an input type of button? Are you sure about that?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to just change it to a button tag and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried this without luck <td><span ng-click="ash()"><button>Edit</button></span></td>

Comment: This looks interesting, your code seems fine.. Maybe it's the dir-paginate that is buggy inside table? Try with the good old ng-repeat and see what happens.. I'll try to play with your code later if noone else finds the answer.

Comment: Thaks @Dalibor. I will look at FrailWords suggestions above and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the working demo of your app, code (one-pager) is enclosed below, but here is the outline:

- removed everything concerning dirPagination directive, replaced by ngRepeat
- removed $log and replaced by console.log
- since I don't have a Web API endpoint, I just populated $scope.Risks with some items on a rejected promise

Try adjusting your solution to first two items (of course, you won't populate it with demo data on rejected promise)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="OpenBoxExtraModule">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>  
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module("OpenBoxExtraModule", []);
app.service('OpenBoxExtraService', function ($http) {
    //Get All Risks
    this.getAllRisks = function () {
        return $http.get("/api/RiskApi");
    }      
});
app.controller("RiskController", function ($scope, OpenBoxExtraService) {
//On load
GetAllRisks();
function GetAllRisks() {
    var promiseGet = OpenBoxExtraService.getAllRisks();
    promiseGet.then(function (pl) { $scope.Risks = pl.data },
        function (errorPl) {
            console.log("Some error in getting risks.", errorPl);
            $scope.Risks = [{RiskID: "1", i3_n_omr: "a", i3_n_2_uwdata_key: "b", RiskReference: "c", PureFacultative:"d", TimestampColumn: "e"},      {RiskID: "2", i3_n_omr: "a", i3_n_2_uwdata_key: "b", RiskReference: "c", PureFacultative:"d", TimestampColumn: "e"},      {RiskID: "3", i3_n_omr: "a", i3_n_2_uwdata_key: "b", RiskReference: "c", PureFacultative:"d", TimestampColumn: "e"}      ];
        });
    }
$scope.ash = function () {
    alert("Bananarama!");}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="RiskController">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Risk ID</th>
            <th>i3_n_omr</th>
            <th>i3_n_2_uwdata_key</th>
            <th>Risk Reference</th>
            <th>Pure Facultative</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="risk in Risks">
            <td><span>{{risk.RiskID}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{risk.i3_n_omr}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{risk.i3_n_2_uwdata_key}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{risk.RiskReference}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{risk.PureFacultative}}</span></td>
            <td><span>{{risk.TimestampColumn}}</span></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="Edit" value="Edit" ng-click="ash()"/></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>
        <div></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help, particularly @FrailWords and @Dalibar. Unbelievably, this was an issue of caching old versions of the javascript files. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use then on your service without resolving a promise inside it.

[fiddle with fallback data](http://jsfiddle.net/7tr2ef2b/1/)

```
this.getAllRisks = function () {

    var d = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/api/RiskApi').then(function (data) {
        d.resolve(data);
    }, function (err) {
        d.reject('no_data');
    });

    return d.promise;

}
```

This will also fix your problem with getting alert to work.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit further please? I'm not sure I follow what you have done. At the moment the "ash" function doesn't use my service.

Comment: $http itself will resolve or reject the promise, and .get returns a promise. You don't have to manually do it.

Comment: So I just need the defer?

Comment: @jshap Your fiddle works with my original service code.

Comment: @jsharp; Dumb Radish used the $http service properly. That's not the issue